# How do I validate to see if a text field has the value that I typed in?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

I've very new to Python and Selenium and I think I need to use the Assert command to verify a text field has what I typed in via Selenium.

I've searched for an hour and can't find the answer.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Ie()

driver.get("https://bie.farmersinsurance.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input"))).send_keys("tess893")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")
assert element.text == "tess893"
```

Here are my results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 265, in main
    wait=args.wait)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 256, in handle_args
    run_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_local.py", line 52, in run_main
    runner(addr, name, kind == 'module', *extra, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\runner.py", line 32, in run
    set_trace=False)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1283, in run
    return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1290, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "c:\_TMP\Test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    assert element.text == "tess893"
AssertionError
```

I don't know why am I getting an `AssertionError`. Based on what I read, it should not throw any errors.

Comment: What are you expecting to return when you compare `element.text` with `tess893`? Assert probably isn't the statement you're looking for; if it fails (i.e. if `element.text` is not equal to `tess893`) then assert will raise the exception you're seeing.

Comment: My goal at the end is to retry typing in the same text field if what I already typed in is not there. This is a very old website that at times, clears the text, and requires trying it again. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: there may also be extra strings, characters in the `element.text` that prevent it from exactly matching the string `"tess893"`, check the contents of `element.text` before using `assert`, such as print(repr(element.text))`, or even `print(len(element.text))` to see that it has the same length of `7` characters as `"tess893"`, etc.

Comment: How interesting. I checked with ```print(len(element.text))``` and result came back as ```0```. Now I'm more confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: I also tried ```print(repr(element.text))``` and results are ```''```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text` is not the property you are looking for.
[It returns the visible text between the elements tags](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--)

You want the `value` of the input element.
To get that, i think you'd use `element.get_attribute('value')`

The assert statement below should work

```
assert element.get_attribute('value') == "tess893"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct in syntax, but that's just how assert works.

`assert (condition)` will do nothing if the condition is true, but if it is false, it will give an error.

"assert" is asserting that `element.text == "tess893"`, if it is giving AssertError, than element.text is NOT equal to "tess893". It could be the xpath being wrong or it containing a different text, not sure though.

Comment: What you have explained is what I have read on how it works. My xpath is correct because I am using right before the assert to send the keys tess893.